# Dual Boot: Ubuntu + Windows 7 with WUBI

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, boot

In my Windows 7 system, I want to install **64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.5** or **Ubuntu-Mate 14.04** as a *native windows application*, but a full length dual-boot system. Earlier it was possible through *Wubi Installer* and I've used that with **32-bit Linux 14.04.1 LTS**. But with my current installation requirement it is not available anymore.

How can make it possible?

Please let me know, if any other information is required.

Answer (score 0):

> At this time, Wubi does not work with Windows 8 default boot-loader.
>   Thus at this point Wubi would not work on a new Windows 8 machine. You
>   would be able to install, but not reboot into Ubuntu.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Comment: The OP does not say he's using Windows 8, he specifically says Windows 7

Comment: Oh. Did the OP change the question? I can't believe I read that as 8. Sorry.

Comment: @Babbzzz..I don't know how have you read it 8, but my platform is 64-bit 7, as mentioned in question and it is not edited ever.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards).

> If one copies the wubi.exe off the cd, it will launch and offer Wubi based installation.

The Wubi.exe is still shipped with the Ubuntu ISO files, and to use it simply extract it into the same directory as the ISO and run it.

There are [many programs](https://www.google.com/search?q=iso%20extractor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) you can use to extract the Wubu.exe file from the ISO, my favorite is [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) which allows you to mount the ISO as a fake CD and then copy the files out.

Comment: But didn't come with my downloaded bundle of Ubuntu. Seems like they have removed it.

Comment: @joy-cs Which one did you download? I tried it with the latest 14.04 64 bit version and it was included